# Appending objects instead of html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am trying to insert some bootstrap elements on mouse click but it seems to insert  `[object Object]`, guess where I am wrong, thanks in advance

**Jquery snippet**

```
// adding skills container
let addSkillsContainer = () =>{
  
    let div_contain =$("<div></div")
    div_contain.addClass("col-md-5")
    div_contain.append(
        $("<div></div").addClass("form-group input-group").append(
            $("<input>").attr("type","text").addClass("form-control")
        )
    )

    let main_container = $(".main-contain")[0]
    main_container.append(div_contain)
}


// event for calling skills add function
$(add).on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    addSkillsContainer()
    console.log('clicked')
    
});
```

Output in html

```
[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have issue in this part of code

```
let main_container = $(".main-contain")[0]
    main_container.append(div_contain)
```

in jQuery if you access like array it return html dom object.

change it to

```
let main_container = $(".main-contain").eq(0)
        main_container.append(div_contain)
```

Comment: well that worked but diff between `$(".main-contain")[0]` and `$(".main-contain").eq(0)` ?

Comment: `$(".main-contain").eq(0)` return jQuery object but `$(".main-contain")[0]` return html dom element object. 
[html element append function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)  and [jquery append function](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let addSkillsContainer = () =>{
    const div_contain =`
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    `;

    $(".main-contain")[0].innerHTML +=div_contain;
}
```

```js
$("#add").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    addSkillsContainer();
    
});

let addSkillsContainer = () =>{
    const div_contain =`
        <div class='col-md-5'>
            <div class="form-group input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    `;

    $(".main-contain")[0].innerHTML +=div_contain;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add</button>

<div class="main-contain">

</div>
```

Comment: still inserting that object